# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types with EF5 and VS 2010

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I had a .NET Framework 4 project running with EF 4.3 and Visual Studio 2010. I have upgraded the project to EF 5 and installe .NET Framework 4.5 on my dev machine. When running my project I now receive "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0"

I'm not using any new features of EF5 or new features of .NET Framework 4.5. What's wrong here ?

Comment: After "could  not load ..." message usually comes the reason why the assembly cannot be loaded. Take a look on the stack trace or place it here.

Comment: Sorry, reason is : The system cannot find the file specified. After further investigation, the problem only happens in debug mode and not in release mode, so this is probably an internal exception that does not surface in release mode.

Comment: Strange that this is happening only in debug mode. Maybe something in the project configuration?

Comment: My Visual Studio is set to break on CLR exceptions. It then breaks on the SaveChanges() method of EF and reports the error (missing assembly). When resuming execution, nothing weird happens, process does not stop in my catch handler below and continues normally until end.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution ! Just install the nuget package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

And then

Solution > References > System.Data.Entity > Properties > Copy Local, and setting it to True.

Note: Copy Local for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types was already set to true, and even though the problem was with System.Data.Entity, the error message was still about Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.

Comment: Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'. :(

Comment: Please, before doing anything you should search it by google .Look at this sites :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/

Comment: This worked for me.  Once I ran the package manager command, a "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" screen appeared with additional instructions.  In my instance, I had to add SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin")); to the Global.asax (under Application_Start method) per the instructions.  Should also mention that I was using VS2015.